# Cubic Diphantine equations of the form $Ax^3-By^3=C$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a method to find all solutions to a Diphantine equation of the form $Ax^3-By^3=C$, where $A,B,C\in\mathbb{Z}$? The quadratic case is the famous Pell's equation, but I am unsure about how to solve this cubic case. According to [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html), Thue showed that it has only a finite number of solutions, which seems to be related, but I could not find the proof.

Comment: look in the book by Hardy 1999,p.78-79

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It seems that the book only said "A very well-known theorem of Thue says that $AX^3-BY^3=l$ (with any integral $A,B,l$) has only a finite number of solutions."

Comment: then Google for another book in the internet

Comment: G. H. Hardy? Writing in 1999? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The title of the book can be found on the link to WolframMathWorld.